# Issues to be aware of when repartitioning

Tags: backup, gparted

I'm planning to repartition my Linux system (sysinfo at the end) using `gparted`, but I've heard it has its risks. Can I please have some advice as to how to make a backup and then restore my system to the backup in case anything goes wrong, and also some general tips on the usage of `gparted` and repartitioning in general?

### System info:

I'm using Linux Mint (with `xfce` although that's probably irrelevant) on dualboot with Windows 10. If needed, I can give extra info on demand. To repartition, I'm using another `xfce` Mint live USB pen.

- ShackER

P.S. I know that similar questions have been posted but I couldn't put them as a comment because I only have 1 rep ;-;

Comment: Welcome! I'm guessing you are going to install Ubuntu after ;-)?

Comment: I'm actually unsure, but I probably will :) (I mean, Mint is a subset of Ubuntu after all) For now, I'm just interested in increasing disk space because it's painfully tiny

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Since you have Windows in dual-boot mode, a simple solution is to use Macrium Reflect Free Edition under Windows.  In my view the program's GUI is a real advantage over most of the Linux offerings.  I have used this program for years and have always been successful when restoring one of its disk images.  See: https://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2016/03/01/a-non-standard-disk-imaging-option-for-linux-users/